# PHP function only working once

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, sql-injection

I'm trying to encrypt three sets of data to insert into MySQL database. However only the first one is working ($email). 
Firstly I post data from a form, make several checks (does the user exist etc...). At this point I encrypt the email to check with the database (already exists). If the data doesn't already exist, it will encrypt the first names and surnames and insert them into the database. 
It does encrypt the first name and surname, but not correctly. Only the email encryption works. (Checked by decrypting the data on another script).

Thanks
Jonathan

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['emailreg'];
$firstna = $_POST['firstna'];
$surna = $_POST['surna'];
$password = $_POST['passreg'];
$passconfirm = $_POST['passconfirm'];
$userpass = $email . $password;
$emailsep = explode("@", $email);
$domain = $emailsep[1];


$key = md5('united');
$salt = md5('united');

function encrypt($string, $key) {
    $string = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
    return $string;
}



$link = mysql_connect('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xxxxxxx", $link);

$domaincheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxxxxxx WHERE domain = '$domain'", $link);
if($domaincheck === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}

$emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxxxxxx WHERE studentemail = '".encrypt($email, $key)."'", $link);
if($emailcheck === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}

$dorow = mysql_fetch_array($domaincheck);
$emailrow = mysql_fetch_array($emailcheck);


if ($password == '') {
$cause = 'Password Blank'; include 'error.php';
}elseif ($passconfirm =='') {
$cause = 'Password Blank'; include 'error.php';
}elseif ($password != $passconfirm) {
$cause = 'Password Mismatch'; include 'error.php';
}elseif ($dorow['domain'] != $domain) {
$cause = 'Incorrect Domain'; include 'error.php';
}elseif ($emailrow['studentemail'] != '') {
$cause = 'User Already Exists'; include 'error.php';
}elseif ($dorow['licensecount'] > $dorow['licensemax']) {
$cause = 'Insufficient Licences'; include 'error.php';
}else {

function hashword($string, $salt){
    $string = crypt($string, '$1$' . $salt . '$');
    return $string;
}




$userpass = hashword($userpass, $salt);


$hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );




$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `xxxxxxx`.`xxxxxxx` (`hash`, `studentemail`, `studentfirstname`, `studentsurname`, `oscopetutcount`, `siggentutcount`, `mmetertutcount`, `lprobetutcount`, `psupplytutcount`, `oscopetest`, `siggentest`, `mmetertest`, `lprobetest`, `psupplytest`, `exam`, `userpass`, `ID`, `domain`, `licensecount`, `licensemax`, `licenceexpire`) VALUES ('$hash', '".encrypt($email, $key)."', '".encrypt($firstna, $key)."', '".encrypt($surna, $key)."', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$userpass', NULL, '', '0', '', NULL)", $link);

$licenceadd = mysql_query("UPDATE xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx SET licensecount = licensecount +1 WHERE domain = '$domain'", $link);

if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); 
}

if($licenceadd === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); 
}

include 'email.php'; 




mysql_close($link); 
}

?>
```

Comment: Using `mysql_` function is highly discouraged because it has been officially deprecated. Please migrate over to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: where does that else get closed up, errors out: `}else {

function hashword($string, $salt){
    $string = crypt($string, '$1$' . $salt . '$');
    return $string;
}`  ... I a just going to close off the if and have no else down there

Comment: Try now, edited my code above. The script was actually two files (include xxxxxxx.php), but I put it together for this post. I missed the end closing else and closing php tag.

Comment: added the `Encryption` tag, bring the heavies in here.

Comment: What is the source of your crypto code? Is it in a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: https://youtu.be/WwxAyiAtrbM    The tutorial is quite eractic though!

Comment: I'd actively discourage anyone from following any of their tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question is concerning security.

Don't use mysql_* library. It is wildly vulnerable to sql injection, especially how you are using it. And it is deprecated.

Let's assume that I pass `joe@gmail.com`

In your code

```
$domain = $emailsep[1];   // will equal "gmail.com"
```

Now let's say I inject it with sql injection, because passing `joe@gmail.com` is rather boring, now isn't it.

I am going to have a lot of fun in this line of code that follows:

```
$domaincheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xxxxxxx WHERE domain = '$domain'", $link);
```

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174).

And use mysqli or pdo as prescribed by those doctors.

---

### **Edit:**

now back to the question you had in mind

### one php file

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); // required something here else exception below
    //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    //ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    //require '1error_2shutdown_3log.php';  // 1. err hndlr, 2. shutdown hndlr, 3. log it somehow


    $b='<br/n>';    // great name huh ?
    $b2='<br/n><br/n>'; // great name huh ?
    echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa").$b;
    echo "s01".$b;
    try {
            echo "s02".$b."--------------------------------------------------------------------------".$b;




        //$email = $_POST['emailreg'];
        //$firstna = $_POST['firstna'];
        //$surna = $_POST['surna'];
        //$password = $_POST['passreg'];
        //$passconfirm = $_POST['passconfirm'];
        //$userpass = $email . $password;
        //$emailsep = explode("@", $email);
        //$domain = $emailsep[1];

        $email = "drewpierce747@gmail.com";
        $firstna = "Drew";
        $surna = "Pierce";
        $password = "secure";
        $passconfirm = "secure";
        $userpass = $email . $password;
        $emailsep = explode("@", $email);
        $domain = $emailsep[1];

        $key = md5('united');   // don't use md5
        $salt = md5('united');  // don't use md5

        function encrypt($string, $key) {
            $b='<br/n>';    // great name huh ?
            $b2='<br/n><br/n>'; // great name huh ?

            # come up with a good key, beyond the scope of this Question
            $key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3"); #32 bytes
            $key_size =  strlen($key);
            echo "Key size: " . $key_size . $b; # 32, big surprise

            # create a random IV to use with CBC encoding
            # yes each time
            $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);    // using ECB cuz u were
            $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);          

            echo "in encrypt() passed <b>",$string,"</b> and <b>",$key.'</b>'.$b;

            $rawEncrypted=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,$iv);
            # prepend the IV for it to be available for decryption
            $rawEncrypted = $iv . $rawEncrypted;
            $b64Encrypted= base64_encode($rawEncrypted); # <------- RIGHT HERE WE ARE DONE

            # basically we are done encrypting, could just return $b64Encrypted and be done with it
            # but no

            #########################################################################
            # lifted from manual page btw: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php
            # do an assert that you can decrypt for a sanity check
            $ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($b64Encrypted);

            # retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
            $iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);

            # retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
            $ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

            # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
            $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv_dec);

            echo  "Assert ... plaintext= ".$plaintext_dec .$b;
            // a real Assert would make it explode, but you get the idea

            #########################################################################

            echo "leaving encrypt() with ",$b64Encrypted.$b2;
            return $b64Encrypted;
        }

        echo "about to connect ...".$b;
        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'GuySmiley', 'mongoose');
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("so_gibberish", $link);

        $domaincheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE domain = '$domain'", $link);
        if($domaincheck === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error());
        }

        //echo "encrypt returns: ".encrypt($email, $key).$b;
        $emailcheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE studentemail = '".encrypt($email, $key)."'", $link);
        if($emailcheck === FALSE) { 
            die(mysql_error());
        }

        $dorow = mysql_fetch_array($domaincheck);
        $emailrow = mysql_fetch_array($emailcheck);

        // the below will explode, I don't have them, changed to echo
        if ($password == '') {
        $cause = 'Password Blank'; echo 'error.php'.$b;
        }elseif ($passconfirm =='') {
        $cause = 'Password Blank'; echo 'error.php'.$b;
        }elseif ($password != $passconfirm) {
        $cause = 'Password Mismatch'; echo 'error.php'.$b;
        }elseif ($dorow['domain'] != $domain) {
        $cause = 'Incorrect Domain'; echo 'error.php'.$b;
        }elseif ($emailrow['studentemail'] != '') {
        $cause = 'User Already Exists'; echo 'error.php'.$b;
        }
        //elseif ($dorow['licensecount'] > $dorow['licensemax']) { # commented out cuz I dont have this table
        //$cause = 'Insufficient Licences'; echo 'error.php'.$b;
        //}else {
        //}

        function hashword($string, $salt){
            $b='<br/n>';    // great name huh ?
            echo "in hashword()".$b;
            $string = crypt($string, '$1$' . $salt . '$');
            return $string;
        }

        echo "s10".$b;
        $userpass = hashword($userpass, $salt);
        echo "s11".$b;
        echo $userpass.$b;

        $hash = md5( rand(0,1000) );    // don't use md5, get a good RNG (random # generator)

        echo "s12".$b;
$sql="INSERT INTO `xxxxxxx`.`xxxxxxx`
(`hash`, `studentemail`, `studentfirstname`, `studentsurname`,
`oscopetutcount`, `siggentutcount`, `mmetertutcount`, `lprobetutcount`,
`psupplytutcount`, `oscopetest`, `siggentest`, `mmetertest`, `lprobetest`,
`psupplytest`, `exam`, `userpass`, `ID`, `domain`, `licensecount`,
`licensemax`, `licenceexpire`)

VALUES ('$hash', '".encrypt($email, $key)."', '".encrypt($firstna, $key)."',
'".encrypt($surna, $key)."', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
'0', '0', '$userpass', NULL, '', '0', '', NULL)";

        echo $sql.$b;
        //$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

        //$licenceadd = mysql_query("UPDATE xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx SET licensecount = licensecount +1 WHERE domain = '$domain'", $link);

        //if($result === FALSE) { 
        //    die(mysql_error()); 
        //}

        //if($licenceadd === FALSE) { 
        //    die(mysql_error()); 
        //}

        //include 'email.php'; 

        echo "near bottom".$b;

        mysql_close($link); 


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), $b;
    } finally {
        echo $b."--------------------------------------------------------------------------".$b."First finally".$b;
    }
?>
```

### Schema that was live when I ran this

```
create table t1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    domain varchar(100) not null,
    key(domain)
);
insert t1(domain) values ('gmail.com'),('yahoo.com'),('ibm.com');

-- drop table t2;
create table t2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    fullName varchar(80) not null,
    studentemail varchar(1000) not null
    -- key(studentemail)
);
-- truncate table t2;
insert t2(fullName,studentemail) values ('Drew Pierce','who-knows');
```

The Screen Ouput:

```
The time is 06:25:20pm
s01
s02
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
about to connect ...


*** begin myLogger function ***
lvl: 8192 | msg:mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead | file:C:\Apache24\htdocs\causes_parse_error.php | ln:82
warn
*** end myLogger function ***

Key size: 32
in encrypt() passed drewpierce747@gmail.com and ��K~:صGc��U��)���^A~/�*�
Assert ... plaintext= drewpierce747@gmail.com
leaving encrypt() with 7n7aTyDo4E4WvtDseUcSM3JMjKipFalVRWhPwu6P5vUdYjN9btNNPo1qlOxB+TKtwfCCr/2ctTCNPxrdVz5Egg==

error.php
s10
in hashword()
s11
$1$3db1a73a$i5Pb3o2s6tV4uWDivvmLA1
s12
Key size: 32
in encrypt() passed drewpierce747@gmail.com and ��K~:صGc��U��)���^A~/�*�
Assert ... plaintext= drewpierce747@gmail.com
leaving encrypt() with uXCKvAUVuBcoPxIbqpbfMZRD50Bu7XSwP75MapBct9UdYjN9btNNPo1qlOxB+TKtwfCCr/2ctTCNPxrdVz5Egg==

Key size: 32
in encrypt() passed Drew and ��K~:صGc��U��)���^A~/�*�
Assert ... plaintext= Drew
leaving encrypt() with 61B1AJtpaK7hx0bFSBNXr9Z0ZFIUkrQXCZcQ5D4pvySzLFfIEEB/2r2FvCLZMobUd3jWRIiyFSfLy4/qTXsT5w==

Key size: 32
in encrypt() passed Pierce and ��K~:صGc��U��)���^A~/�*�
Assert ... plaintext= Pierce
leaving encrypt() with /JFBohEe96R7sFnQxu+ujvgFv8WZl9Pdss+zv8tVptJk2xrZH8Pb3xjfGmWGH92W/h4aeWrPS8ICEIojKtYrgw==

INSERT INTO `xxxxxxx`.`xxxxxxx` (`hash`, `studentemail`, `studentfirstname`, `studentsurname`, `oscopetutcount`, `siggentutcount`, `mmetertutcount`, `lprobetutcount`, `psupplytutcount`, `oscopetest`, `siggentest`, `mmetertest`, `lprobetest`, `psupplytest`, `exam`, `userpass`, `ID`, `domain`, `licensecount`, `licensemax`, `licenceexpire`) VALUES ('a96b65a721e561e1e3de768ac819ffbb', 'uXCKvAUVuBcoPxIbqpbfMZRD50Bu7XSwP75MapBct9UdYjN9btNNPo1qlOxB+TKtwfCCr/2ctTCNPxrdVz5Egg==', '61B1AJtpaK7hx0bFSBNXr9Z0ZFIUkrQXCZcQ5D4pvySzLFfIEEB/2r2FvCLZMobUd3jWRIiyFSfLy4/qTXsT5w==', '/JFBohEe96R7sFnQxu+ujvgFv8WZl9Pdss+zv8tVptJk2xrZH8Pb3xjfGmWGH92W/h4aeWrPS8ICEIojKtYrgw==', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '$1$3db1a73a$i5Pb3o2s6tV4uWDivvmLA1', NULL, '', '0', '', NULL)
near bottom

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
First finally
```

Basically, I am happy with the way the ASSERTS are coming out, with the embedded IVs (initialization vectors).

Writing to the database **wasn't** the issue with this question, as you can see a commented out that area. Rather, it was a question about encryption / decryption.

The recipient of the cipher text can decrypt it as the IV in prepended, and they will have the key. If they don't have the key, too bad.

Good luck ! And change that library over to ... like ... **PDO** !

Comment: k, thanks. I had someone inject my database (with permission) so that I could see how easy it was for someone to reach the data. He said that the data was well encrypted, but I will implement the inject protection procedures. Do you have any ideas why the encryption isn't working multiple times?

Comment: oh, you mean the actual question :> Ok I will get back to you if no one does beforehand. Loading it up now ...

Comment: I'm still waiting for the Great Purge when a marauding band of PHP programmers finds and deletes every old PHP tutorial that uses `mysql_`.

Comment: @alexw I'll lead the charge.